# Antiderivative $\int x f(x) e^{-x}$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, derivatives

I'm trying to represent the antiderivative $\int x f(x) e^{-x}$ via $A = \int xf(x)$ and $B = \int f(x)e^{-x}$. My attempt with the integration by parts: neither

$$
\int xf(x)e^{-x} = (\int xf(x)) \times e^{-x} + \int ((\int xf(x))) \times e^{-x} = A e^{-x} + \int Ae^{-x} 
$$

nor

$$
\int xf(x)e^{-x} = x \times (\int f(x)e^{-x}) - \int (\int f(x)e^{-x}) = x B - \int B
$$

works since there exists always $A$ or $B$ under the integration.

Many thanks for any hint.

Comment: why dont you take xf(x) as the first part (u) and e^-x as the second part v. Its supposed to be in that order according to ILATE

Comment: when I do that, the antiderivative of xf'(x)e^{-x} occurs, it seems even harder than the original antiderivative

Comment: I don't know why you have so much trouble. You don't even have a $dx$ or $dy$ or $d\theta$. Decide you're integrating with $dz$ and all the rest is a constant.

Comment: @MasB Thank you, but I don't understand what you mean. Which is "the rest"? Could you please make it more clear?

Comment: My comment was meant as a bit of humor. You forgot, everywhere, to indicate what is the variable of integration ($dx$). So I suggested you integrate with respect to $z$ and then the integrand is a constant with regards to $z$.

Comment: Ah, ha ha, that's funny. I didn't put the differential dx (it's quite clear from the context).

Comment: Watch out for the "context". A teacher could ask a question without the $dx$ to which the answer would be "not integrable" or "doesn't make sense" or to integrate a difficult integrand in $x$ and ask for the integral with $dz$. All symbols are important in math. When a symbol is absent, of course "context" is a good guide, but not always...